# Running multiple models within a Toolbox (.tbx) with 1 python script

Tags: arcpy, loop, iteration, model, toolbox

I am trying to run over 80 models between 2 toolboxes. I know I can list them out to run them (example #2) but is there a way to iterate/loop through each model and run them one at a time without having to list them all out like in (example #1).

Here is the code right now that I am working on. I am stuck on how to insert the model name after either arcpy."" or tbx1."".

Example #1

```
import arcpy 
 
tbx1 = arcpy.AddToolbox("\\\sce\\folders\\eGIS\\0_Templates\\APRX\\Automation_Projects\\Append_to_QC_V1.tbx", 'AppendtoQCv1')    

tools = arcpy.ListTools("*_AppendtoQCv1")
for t in tools:  
  try:
    arcpy.t() #<<<<This doesnt work. AttributeError: module 'arcpy' has no attribute 't'
    print(t) #This does give me the list of models I am looking to use.
  except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
```

Using print(t) I get the whole list that looks like this:
Model1_AppendtoQCv1,
Model2_AppendtoQCv1,
Model3_AppendtoQCv1

Example #2

This is the code that does work and what I am trying to not have to copy then alter over and over many times for each model name.

```
import arcpy   
tbx1 = arcpy.AddToolbox("\\\Automation_Projects\\Append_to_QC_V1.tbx")
tbx2 = arcpy.AddToolbox("\\\Automation_Projects\\Update_Attributes_v1")

try:
        tbx1.PipeJoinMethod()
        print("Finished Append: PipeJoinMethod")
        tbx2.PipeJoinMethod()
        print("Finished Updating Attributes: PipeJoinMethod")
except arcpy.ExecuteError:
        print(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
```

Comment: `getattr(arcpy, t)()`